Key vaults keys, secrets, and certificates PS script
I am trying to list all the keys, secrets, and certificates that are either expired or going to be expire in 20 days from multiple key vaults from multiple subscriptions but receiving the PS script error.
I need an output in a table format that includes subscription name, key vault name, object category like keys or secrets or certificates, object name, expired date and expires in how many days. I'm trying to run the script in automation account runbook but I'm getting error.
Error in Automation Runbbok
Connect-AzAccount -Identity

$AlertBeforeDays = 20

# Function to get expiring items from a Key Vault
function Get-ExpiringItems {
    param (
        [string]$VaultName,
        [datetime]$ExpiryDate
    )

    $ExpiringItems = @()

    # Check for expired or expiring keys
    $Keys = Get-AzKeyVaultKey -VaultName $VaultName
    $ExpiringKeys = $Keys | Where-Object { $_.Attributes.Expires -lt $ExpiryDate }
    $ExpiringKeys | ForEach-Object {
        $ExpiringItems += [PSCustomObject]@{
            VaultName = $VaultName
            ItemType = "Key"
            ItemName = $_.Key.Kid
            ExpiryDate = $_.Attributes.Expires
        }
    }

    # Check for expired or expiring secrets
    $Secrets = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName
    $ExpiringSecrets = $Secrets | Where-Object { $_.Attributes.Expires -lt $ExpiryDate }
    $ExpiringSecrets | ForEach-Object {
        $ExpiringItems += [PSCustomObject]@{
            VaultName = $VaultName
            ItemType = "Secret"
            ItemName = $_.Id
            ExpiryDate = $_.Attributes.Expires
        }
    }

    # Check for expired or expiring certificates
    $Certificates = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $VaultName
    $ExpiringCertificates = $Certificates | Where-Object { $_.Attributes.Expires -lt $ExpiryDate }
    $ExpiringCertificates | ForEach-Object {
        $ExpiringItems += [PSCustomObject]@{
            VaultName = $VaultName
            ItemType = "Certificate"
            ItemName = $_.Id
            ExpiryDate = $_.Attributes.Expires
        }
    }

    return $ExpiringItems
}

# Get current date and date 20 days from now
$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$ExpiryDate = $CurrentDate.AddDays($AlertBeforeDays)

# Initialize array to hold all expiring items
$AllExpiringItems = @()

# Get all subscriptions
$Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

# Loop through each subscription
foreach ($Subscription in $Subscriptions) {
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $Subscription.Id

    # Get all Key Vaults in the subscription
    $KeyVaults = Get-AzKeyVault

    # Loop through each Key Vault
    foreach ($KeyVault in $KeyVaults) {
        $VaultName = $KeyVault.VaultName
        $ExpiringItems = Get-ExpiringItems -VaultName $VaultName -ExpiryDate $ExpiryDate
        $AllExpiringItems += $ExpiringItems
    }
}

# Output the expiring items in table format
$AllExpiringItems | Format-Table -Property VaultName, ItemType, ItemName, ExpiryDate -AutoSize


As you dealing with multiple subscription try to include SubscriptionName and DaysUntilExpiry in the configuration @manjuS

Yeah, or is there any better way also its fine

To list all the keys, secrets, and certificates that are either expired or going to be expire in 20 days from multiple key vaults from multiple subscriptions, you can refer below sample PowerShell script:
$AlertBeforeDays = 20

function Get-ExpiringItems {
    param (
        [string]$VaultName,
        [string]$SubscriptionName,
        [datetime]$ExpiryDate
    )

    $ExpiringItems = @()

    $Keys = Get-AzKeyVaultKey -VaultName $VaultName
    $ExpiringKeys = $Keys | Where-Object { $_.Expires -ne $null -and $_.Expires -lt $ExpiryDate }
    $ExpiringKeys | ForEach-Object {
        $ExpiringItems += [PSCustomObject]@{
            SubscriptionName = $SubscriptionName
            VaultName        = $VaultName
            ItemType         = "Key"
            ItemName         = $_.Id
            ExpiryDate       = $_.Expires
            ExpiryInDays     = ($_.Expires - (Get-Date)).Days
            Status           = if ($_.Expires -lt (Get-Date)) { "Expired" } else { "Expiring Soon" }
        }
    }

    $Secrets = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName $VaultName
    $ExpiringSecrets = $Secrets | Where-Object { $_.Expires -ne $null -and $_.Expires -lt $ExpiryDate }
    $ExpiringSecrets | ForEach-Object {
        $ExpiringItems += [PSCustomObject]@{
            SubscriptionName = $SubscriptionName
            VaultName        = $VaultName
            ItemType         = "Secret"
            ItemName         = $_.Id
            ExpiryDate       = $_.Expires
            ExpiryInDays     = ($_.Expires - (Get-Date)).Days
            Status           = if ($_.Expires -lt (Get-Date)) { "Expired" } else { "Expiring Soon" }
        }
    }

    $Certificates = Get-AzKeyVaultCertificate -VaultName $VaultName
    $ExpiringCertificates = $Certificates | Where-Object { $_.Expires -ne $null -and $_.Expires -lt $ExpiryDate }
    $ExpiringCertificates | ForEach-Object {
        $ExpiringItems += [PSCustomObject]@{
            SubscriptionName = $SubscriptionName
            VaultName        = $VaultName
            ItemType         = "Certificate"
            ItemName         = $_.Id
            ExpiryDate       = $_.Expires
            ExpiryInDays     = ($_.Expires - (Get-Date)).Days
            Status           = if ($_.Expires -lt (Get-Date)) { "Expired" } else { "Expiring Soon" }
        }
    }

    return $ExpiringItems
}

$CurrentDate = Get-Date
$ExpiryDate = $CurrentDate.AddDays($AlertBeforeDays)

$AllExpiringItems = @()

$Subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

foreach ($Subscription in $Subscriptions) {
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $Subscription.Id
    $SubscriptionName = $Subscription.Name

    $KeyVaults = Get-AzKeyVault

    foreach ($KeyVault in $KeyVaults) {
        $VaultName = $KeyVault.VaultName
        $ExpiringItems = Get-ExpiringItems -VaultName $VaultName -SubscriptionName $SubscriptionName -ExpiryDate $ExpiryDate
        $AllExpiringItems += $ExpiringItems
    }
}

$AllExpiringItems | Format-Table -Property SubscriptionName, VaultName, ItemType, ItemName, ExpiryDate, ExpiryInDays, Status -AutoSize

Response:


The above PS script and the PS script shared by me only works when we have single subscription but if we want to parse the keys, secrets, and certificates from multiple key vaults from multiple subscriptions I think we need to modify the PS script. @Sridevi

What error you are getting when you are running above script in multiple subscriptions environment? In my case, I have only 1 subscription so I cannot reproduce it

When you run Get-AzSubscription command, are you able to get all subscriptions info in response?

Yes, I'm able to get only subscription info

U mean you are getting single subscription info?

Yes, only subscription info

When you sign in as user, are you getting all subscriptions?

I'm trying to run the PS script in automation account runbook but I'm receiving the error.
You may need to login again after updating "EnableLoginByWam".
Unable to acquire token for tenant 'organizations' with error 'DeviceCodeCredential authentication failed: Verification code expired before contacting the server'
DeviceCodeCredential authentication failed: Verification code expired before contacting the server

Could you confirm whether the managed identity of automation account has access under all subscriptions or not? Do you have multiple subscription in single tenant?

I have multiple subscription in a single tenant and yes, I have provided system assigned identity with the azure role assignments as key vault reader.

Could you edit your question and add managed identity role assignments image from Portal?
